# Медленная прокрутка ScrollView

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-fragment, прокрутка

У меня есть scroll и работает он замечательно, но есть некое зависание: при прокрутке вниз (до конца и это делается за один свайп) оно доходит, а вот обратно за один свайп это не сделать, нужно много раз свайпать, чтобы вернутся. Вот код xml:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/save"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="@string/profile"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
                android:id="@+id/profile_fragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="@string/car"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
                android:id="@+id/car_fragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="@string/photo"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
                android:id="@+id/photos_fragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>


    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/save"
        style="@style/YellowButton"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="21dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
        android:text=""
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:text="@string/save"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/save"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/scrollView3" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Ничего подобного раньше не встречал и решения не нашёл. Буду благодарен за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Какой контент находится внутри фрагментов? Попробуй сжать изображения, если они большого разрешения, у меня при аналогичной проблеме сработало.